# 401 unauthorized while connecting to SharePoint Online via code

Tags: authentication, active-directory, kerberos, adfs

We have an intranet application hosted in IIS which runs on service account + windows authentication + enabled impersonation. The currently logged in user connects to SharePoint online and get some search data is the goal of the application.

It's a claim based authentication. In the code, browser instance is created and takes many redirection for authentication and receives FEDAuth cookies. It started giving 401 unauthorized error when it goes to ADFS (confirmed via log) or sometimes request is times out.

This use to work fine in on-prim but when moved to Azure this issue started!!

Note: Service account is recreated when moved to Azure and not sure what went wrong? shared the service acc delegation in AD

[image]